# Finding the best template library with CI HMVC

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I recently moved to HMVC structure in my project, and I want to find the best solution for template library.

I have the latest version of CI (2.1.3) and HMVC (5.4)

I'm looking for template library, which:

- support HMVC structure
- have active community (frequent updates)
- have a good tutorial

If you working with the same library - please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this philsturgeon template library https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template